# python3 psycopg SQL identifier must be string

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python, psycopg2

I am trying to reference dynamic tables and fields in a tkinter GUI project using MySQLdb. Using psycopg2.sql to handle an insert statement.

The user select a code, size and color and inputs a quantity. The table names are made up of the size and the code (eg. size-small and code-1111, table_name=small1111). Then the color is the column name and the quantity is an integer entered into the field. The inputs are saved in a dictionary (tdict) when the user selects them. And the dictionary elements are called to be saved in the database table.

```
table_name = tdict['Size']+tdict['Code']
stmnt = ("INSERT INTO {} (%s, Date) VALUES(%s, %s)").format(sql.Identifier((table_name, tdict['Color'])))
c.execute(sql.SQL(stmnt, (tdict['Quantity'], date)))
```

The insert query is giving me a TypeError

TypeError("SQL identifiers must be strings")

Can anyone please help? What am I doing wrong? How should the Identifier be made to behave as a string?
Note: I've tried to pass the Identifier elements through a str class but it didn't work. ie

```
stmnt = ("INSERT INTO {} (%s, Date) VALUES(%s, %s)").format(sql.Identifier((str(table_name, tdict['Color']))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking `sql.Identifier()` to create an identifier out of a tuple, e.g. `('small1111','magenta')`.  Because `format()` [only substitutes into braces](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.SQL.format) `{}` (and not `%s`), I think what you actually had in mind was this:

```
stmnt = sql.SQL("INSERT INTO {} ({}, Date) VALUES(%s %s)").format( sql.Identifier(table_name), sql.Identifier(tdict['Color']) )
```

I'd suggest you rethink your database design, though --- you should probably have columns named `size`, `code`, and `color` rather than separate tables and columns for each.  That will prevent you from having to add a new column each time a new color or a new table for each new size or code. `SELECT count(*) FROM inventory WHERE size = 'small' AND code = '1111' GROUP BY color` seems preferable to having to create queries dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

This error message will also appear when you have a typo error where you should have used sql.Literal('someFixedNumber'), but instead using sq.Identifier('someFixedNumber')